# PHP Signup not working using prepare sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I wrote code for sign up using php and mysql prepare statement.
I dont know why its not inserting record!
Can anyone tell where is the problem
Its not displaying any error or success message even
here is my adduser.php code

```
<?php 

 include 'config.php';

 //checkusername
 $check = $con->prepare("select username from users");

 while($row = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     if($row['username'] == $_POST['username'])
        echo -1;
     else{

        $sql = $con->prepare("insert into users(name,username,password) values(?,?,?)");
        $sql->bindParam($name,$username,$password);
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $sql->execute();
            echo 1;
     }
   }

 ?>
```

Comment: That is not how you use [`bindParam`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). That is to bind a single parameter per call, not all 3 at once.

Comment: You might have mixed up documentation. This is a mix of mysqli binding and PDO. You can just put `$name,$username,$password` in an array in the `execute` call with PDO though (after variables are defined). e.g. `$sql->execute(array($name,$username,$password));` shouldn't use `md5` for hashing either though.

Comment: From PHP's [md5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) manual: "_Warning It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm. See the [Password Hashing FAQ](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash) for details and best practices._"

Comment: `$check = $con->prepare("select username from users");` would be better as `$check = $con->prepare("select username from users where username = ?");`

Comment: If the answer below helped you, please remember to upvote it and/or mark it as "accepted", thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql->bindParam($name,$username,$password);
```

is incorrect. You must bind each parameter via a separate call to bindParam.

See the argument list and examples in the PHP [manual page for bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) to understand what the function accepts as input, and how to use it in practice.

e.g.

```
$sql = $con->prepare("insert into users(name,username,password) values(?,?,?)");
$sql->bindParam(1, $name);
$sql->bindParam(2, $username);
$sql->bindParam(3, $password);
...
$sql->execute();
```

Alternatively, you can simply call the [execute function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) and pass in an array of parameters that way:

```
$sql = $con->prepare("insert into users(name,username,password) values(?,?,?)");
$params = [$name, $username, $password];
$sql->execute($params);
```

---

P.S. if you were not getting any kind of error or indication of this problem when you ran the code, then please ensure you [enabled PHP's error logging feature](https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/) and [PDO's exception reporting mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) so you can get detailed information about any errors in your code.

P.P.S. Please don't store passwords using the obsolete, insecure md5 algorithm - that is a security risk. Learn about PHP's built-in, up-to-date, secure [password hashing and verification functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead.

P.P.P.S. It makes no sense to query all the users and loop through them to find any existing records with the same username. This is very inefficient. You can filter the results much more quickly and efficiently using a SQL `WHERE` clause in the `SELECT`, e.g. `select username from users where username = ?`. Bind the username to that, and you'll get a single row back in response if there's a match.